# Using nested IF in Google Sheets

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, nested, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm trying to create multiple IF in a single cell so if the cell states "Critical", then adjacent cells should state "response required within 24hrs". If the cell states "Medium", the adjacent cell should state "response required within 48hrs". If it states "Low", then the adjacent should state "Response required after other priorities are address"... how do I create that formula?

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
=IF(A1="Critical"; "response required within 24hrs";
 IF(A1="Medium";   "response required within 48hrs";
 IF(A1="Low";      "response required after other priorites are addresse"; )))
```

---

for array like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
 IF(A1:A10="Critical"; "response required within 24hrs";
 IF(A1:A10="Medium";   "response required within 48hrs";
 IF(A1:A10="Low";      "response required after other priorites are addresse"; ))))
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be easier if you use a `SWITCH` statement instead of multiple chained `IF`s.

The generic formula looks like: `SWITCH(expression, case1, value1, [case2_or_default, …], [value2, …])`

So for your special use case it will look like this:

```
=SWITCH([CELL-TO-COMPARE],"Critical","response required within 24hrs","Medium","response required within 48hrs","Low","Response required after other priorites are addresse")
```

Have fun, cheers